# Resource not found error in running the app cloned from GitHub on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies

I cloned [this app](https://github.com/wiltonribeiro/grocery_shop_flutter) from GitHub with the latest Android Studio through version control. After opening the project I got the dependencies and clicked run.

It gives, **in short**, the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  Output:  O:\grocery_shop_flutteranalysis\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:86: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  O:\grocery_shop_flutteranalysis\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:87: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  error: failed linking references.

  Output:  C:\Users\arsla\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.1.0.aar\18619ad8df18189ffa8d36e63947ac33\res\values\values.xml:174:5-210:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

  C:\Users\arsla\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.1.0.aar\18619ad8df18189ffa8d36e63947ac33\res\values\values.xml:174:5-210:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

  error: failed linking references.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: can anyone clone this project and try to run to see if the error still persists

Answer (score 0):

I can see clearly there that:

1. `resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found`
2. `resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found`

Did you check `\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml` file? Is it really correct?

Comment: i am a newbie can you tell me how to look this up please

Comment: i cant locate this
\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml

Comment: i just cloned it from git hub .could there be something missing in the original project